# Viewbag assign value for each iteration results in error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to dynamically set a value for each iteration of

```
        int index = 0;
        foreach (var item in model.ResponseRetest)
        {  
            var result = _pointService.GetBuildings(item.ID).Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x, Value = x }).ToList();
            ViewBag.Company[index] = result;
            index++;
        }
```

Even though result does have a value, I am getting the following error:

```
    Message "Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ViewBag this way is not recommended as it creates overhead in unboxing the data with every iteration (in this case, Company).  The error is likely happening on the first iteration because you're applying indexing on non-existent property Company.

```
    List<List<datatype>> companyResults = new List<List<datatype>>();

    foreach (var item in model.ResponseRetest)
    {  
        var result = _pointService.GetBuildings(item.ID).Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x, Value = x }).ToList();
        companyResults.Add(result);
    }

    ViewBag.Company = companyResults;
```